# Title Order is not expected, when Access Pivot exported to Excel File.

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, export, pivot

I export Access pivots to Excel files, and some of them are having not correct column order -- I'd like to have the total column is sure to be at the end of columns as follos;

Expected:

```
StaffCode, Name, 2018/04, 2018/05, 2018/06, TOTAL
```

Result:

```
StaffCode, Name, 2018/04, TOTAL, 2018/06, 2018/05 
<-- TOTAL column is coming before/in pivot columns unexpectedly (some pivot comes as expected)
```

Usually, I convert pivot query to table and then copy recordset to new excel file.
If you've overcame this kind of issue, please let me know about your solutions.

pivot query:

```
TRANSFORM 
    CDbl(Nz(SUM(TotalHours),0)) AS TotalHours
SELECT
    StaffCode,
    StaffName,
    SUM(TotalHours) AS TOTAL
FROM
    SRC_TABLE
GROUP BY
    StaffCode,
    StaffName
ORDER BY
    StaffCode
PIVOT 
   REG_YM;
```

convert query to table:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", Application.CurrentDb.Name, acTable, SrcQueryName, ConvTblName, False
```

export to excel:

```
Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset(TableName, dbOpenTable)
Set Ws = objExcel.Worksheets("XXXX")
 Ws.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rst
```

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: could that be related to the `Transform` behaviour? If you run the `Transform` code in Access, does it **always** come out correctly?

Comment: you may find some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329806/fields-in-the-wrong-order-when-importing-from-csv-to-access) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/79fcd5c8-2346-4fb1-85b6-c5d3a212f47d/how-do-i-enforce-output-order-of-a-table-docmdtransferspreadsheet-does-not-write-records-to-excel?forum=accessdev). Also, would the `DoCmd.TranferSpreadsheet` be helpful?

Comment: @Our Man in Bananas, Many thanks for your kind advice!  I still have the same issue with DoCmd.TranferSpreadsheet, but thanks to you, I noticed other good things to use it -- before I thought I couldn't export to paticular sheet by DoCmd.TranferSpreadsheet, but it can (ref. #3 in http://access-excel.tips/access-vba-cocmd-transferspreadsheet/). And your reference, espacially the last one really helped me a lot. I'm so grateful all of your considerations.