# Import .csv file to MSAccess table without losing leading zeros

Tags: csv, ms-access, import, vba, leading-zero

My objective is to automate the import of a .csv file into an Access table, retaining all data in the csv file, specifically leading zeros.

The csv file will have a varying number of columns every time, so the table it needs to be imported into will have to be created on the fly.
Also, the decision was made to have every column defined as text(255).

Here's the relevant code for that process, leaving out the part where the user navigates to a folder and selects a .csv file.

Notes on variables:

**FilePathAndName** contains the full path and file name of the .csv file

**TableName**       contains the name of the MSAccess table I am creating

**HeaderRow**       contains the first row of the csv file which has column names. The column names will never contain a comma.

**ColumnNames()**   is an array to hold the column names themselves.

**SQLStatement**    will hold a SQL DDL statement to create the table

```
Open FilePathAndName For Input As #1

' read first row to get column names because that will change every time
Line Input #1, HeaderRow
Close #1
ColumnNames = Split(HeaderRow, ",")

' create MSAccess table via DDL commands
TableName = "GROUPS_TEST"
SQLStatement = "CREATE TABLE " & TableName & "("
For i = 0 To UBound(ColumnNames)
    SQLStatement = SQLStatement & "[" & ColumnNames(i) & "] text(255)"
    If i < UBound(ColumnNames) Then
        SQLStatement = SQLStatement & ", "
    End If
Next i
SQLStatement = SQLStatement & ")"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLStatement

' load .csv file into the table that was just created
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , TableName, FilePathAndName, True
```

It works flawlessly down to and including the DoCmd.RunSQL statement where the table is created.
All columns are defined as text(255) because there are some columns which have leading zeros which must be retained.
They are not numbers; they are alphanumeric values.
Then the trouble begins. I execute the TransferText action and the data is imported to the table from the .csv file.
**Except that it strips leading zeros from the values that have them
 even though I specifically defined all columns as TEXT columns.**

I've been googling for a couple of hours and nothing has turned up.
I don't have an import/export specification because of the dynamic nature of the .csv files.
And I don't know that it would make any difference anyway.

One thing that was mentioned was editing a registry setting for text files in MSAccess but I could not find specifics.
I'm using Access 2007.
Another idea brought up was using a schema.ini file but again due to the dynamic nature of the csv files I don't know if that would work.

Any help will be gratefully accepted. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the leading zero's dynamic or is the field length fixed? If fixed, you could set the columns format property to retain the leading zeros

Comment: since you are reading the file to get the column count, what is stopping you to loop through the line and insert all rows? i know this is not the answer you wanted but just saying. BTW. If you really want to fix this, add an empty/test row on top of your .csv file that all coumns have text values. it will force access to read all columns as Text, otherwise Access converts columns while transferring and yours is one of its side effect.

Comment: @random_answer_guy - leading zeros are dynamic.

Comment: @krishKM - yeah I was hoping to avoid looping through the file; instead, I wanted to "bulk insert" it into the table. And, I tried inserting a test row right after the header row with non-numeric values for the problematic columns. No luck.It still stripped off the leading zeros on subsequent rows. Thanks for your input!

Comment: this problem is very familiar but not sure how I did it. i think access evaluates either 1st row or first 10 rows to identify the data type. (i know its stupid) if you really want to be sure, just insert it line by line at least you know what you did..

Comment: @Carl, just tried myself. Leading zeros remain when I used at least 5 dummy records (non-numeric values only).

Comment: @Rene, thank you for the input. I believe I have found the underlying issue. I need to do some more testing but if it turns out to be correct, I will post back here with my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the field names from the import file, name all of the fields in the import table F1, F2, F3, etc.
Set the HasFieldNames parameter to false. Then the first row will always be text. You can delete that row later.
Then either change the field names to what you want or insert the data into another table. I always use this method anyway, so that I can clean up the import data before inserting it into final destination tables.

Comment: Set HasFieldNames to false. Got error "The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'F1'. etc, etc.

Comment: And, the field names must be the first row because that's how I determine the column names for creating the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for me; credit to Ryan Griffin for his answer to a similar question on Stack Overflow.

Re-stating the requirements:

1) import a .csv file into MSAccess

2) must retain all leading zeros in fields that have them

3) .csv file is dynamic; the number of columns can (and usually does) vary with every import

4) data type can be Text for all columns

5) length of data for a given column will never be > 255

6) first row of .csv file will always contain column names and a column name will never have a comma in it

7) columns may or may not have quote delimiters; if any column contains a comma then that column will be quote-delimited; otherwise it may or may not be.

Here's a sample .csv file:

Name,Department,Extension

"ManyJohns, John",02,0987

John Smallberries,"Acquisitions","32939"

"John Bigbootie",0001,GIGO

---

System setup: Windows 7 and MSAccess 2007

I was aware of a registry setting which helped on a similar project years ago.
Win7 path is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Text

Change the value of **ImportMixedTypes** from **Majority Type** to **Text**

First try: using the TransferText action

Variables: TableName and FilePathAndName

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , TableName, FilePathAndName, True

Note that there is no import specification because as mentioned above it can change every time.
Result: Dropped leading zeros and removed text values

[image]

---

Second try: opening the .csv file as an Access object

Variables: TableName, FilePath and FileName

```
SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO " & TableName & " SELECT * FROM [TEXT;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;CharacterSet=437;DATABASE=" & FilePath & "].[" & FileName & "]"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLStatement
```

Result: I had never seen this used before; kind of cool, I thought. But, it also dropped leading zeros and removed text values.

[image]

---

Third try: dynamically creating an import/export specification
Here's the post from Ryan Griffin whose solution I adapted for my purposes. Thank you sir; I salute you.

[Access Data Project Importing CSV File In VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413740/access-data-project-importing-csv-file-in-vba/11147920#11147920)

And, success.

[image]

Because of the dynamic nature of my .csv files, here's the final code based on Ryan's work.
I did not include variable declarations here; if interested let me know and I'll put something together a little more polished.

```
Private Function CreateImportSpecification()

    'based on solution from Ryan Griffin 21-JUN-2012
    ImportSpecificationName = "ImportSpec_" & TableName

    xml = ""
    xml = xml & "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>" & vbCrLf
    xml = xml & "<ImportExportSpecification Path=" & Chr(34) & FilePathAndName & Chr(34) & " xmlns=""urn:www.microsoft.com/office/access/imexspec"">" & vbCrLf
    xml = xml & "   <ImportText TextFormat=""Delimited"" FirstRowHasNames=""true"" FieldDelimiter="","" CodePage=""437"" Destination=" & Chr(34) & TableName & Chr(34) & " >" & vbCrLf
    xml = xml & "      <DateFormat DateOrder=""MDY"" DateDelimiter=""/"" TimeDelimiter="":"" FourYearDates=""true"" DatesLeadingZeros=""false"" />" & vbCrLf
    xml = xml & "      <NumberFormat DecimalSymbol=""."" />" & vbCrLf
    xml = xml & "         <Columns PrimaryKey=""{none}"">" & vbCrLf

    ' dynamically populate the 'FieldName' property of the <Column> attribute
    For i = 0 To UBound(ColumnNames)
        xml = xml & "            <Column Name=""Col" & (i + 1) & """ FieldName=""" & ColumnNames(i) & """ Indexed=""NO"" SkipColumn=""false"" DataType=""Text"" Width=""255"" />" & vbCrLf
    Next i

    xml = xml & "         </Columns>" & vbCrLf
    xml = xml & "   </ImportText>" & vbCrLf
    xml = xml & "</ImportExportSpecification>"

    ' if a specification already exists for this table, delete it
    With CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications
        For i = 0 To .Count - 1
            If .Item(i).Name = ImportSpecificationName Then
                .Item(i).Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        ' add the specification to the database
        .Add ImportSpecificationName, xml
        ' could execute ImportSpecificationName right here
        ' but would need to loop through the ImportExportSpecifications again
        ' to make sure you had the right one
    End With

    DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport ImportSpecificationName

End Function
```

The only thing I can figure is that MSAccess ignores the registry key (or I am modifying the wrong one) when importing a .csv file.
Ultimately, the only thing that worked for me was to dynamically create an import/export specification.
Any additional input is welcome.